# Trying to Databind to gridview

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to Databind to grid view but I am having some problems here

```
    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    bs.DataSource = (From u In threeContext.dbConext.skechersDeliveries Where u.isprocessed = False Select u).ToList()

    dgDeliverys.DataSource = bs
```

This works but when I update the values it does not get saved to database when i leave the row of the gridview?

Comment: you have to call threeContext.SaveChanges to forward changes to the source database.

Comment: @AlinI correct budy I was calling a fresh dbcontext cant beleive that put a proper anser in their thanks do you no how one would retrist gridview entry textbox to numbers only

Comment: in cellvalidating event put: **e.Cancel = Not IsNumeric(e.FormattedValue)**

Comment: and also see the way I created the linq their how do I go about giving proper column names to the columns created in the gridview thanks very much for above answer

Comment: do a Select new with{.myColumnName = u.columnName, .myOtherColumn = u.someothercolumn}

Comment: It's better to go to the Columns window of the DataGridView and put in HeaderText the names you want to show on the DGV.

Comment: Oops... misread your last comment. Use the HeaderText property in the gridview columns. You will need to specify your columns i.e. you cannot use AutoGenerateColumns = true

Comment: @Alin... yes you are right I was just correcting myself at the same time as you posted your comment.

Comment: or handle the DataBindingComplete event of the datagridview and loop through all the columns checking the DataPropertyName in a select case and change the HeaderText there.

Comment: @AlinI When I do that i get no data being displayed i meen if i create the columns through the column editor

Comment: you have to put columns names (names returned by the Linq query) in the DataPropertyName field for each column.

Comment: @AlinI can you provide  a code example to this answer and included an example of how to do that ?

Comment: change your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

For you question (make sure `datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = True`):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
Handles datagridview1.CellValidating
    e.Cancel = Not IsNumeric(DataGridView1.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex))
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) _
Handles DataGridView1.DataBindingComplete
    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        Select Case col.DataPropertyName
            Case "Col1" ' from Table or Linq
                col.HeaderText = "My Column 1"
            Case "Col2" ' from Table or Linq
                col.HeaderText = "My Column 2"
                ' '' etc for each column
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```